# What if someone sniffs your encrypted cookie data and send it to the server as it is?

Tags: php, security, cookies, encryption, https

This might be an irrelevant question , but I'm wondering whether this can happen..

In HTTPS cookie data like `phpssid` transfers as an encrypted big random number.

What if someone sniffs that encrypted random number and send it to the server as it is? So the server decrypt that id and allows the hacker to log in as someone else. Is this possible?

Comment: In what way are you imagining they sniff the cookie? Use HTTP-only and Secure flags on the cookie. Prevent XSS attacks on your site.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan like someone in the same network that we are connected to or being in the middle of a connection can hijack the session right ?

Comment: one cannot hijack or sniff HTTPS. If you're concerned about SSLStrip, that only happens over HTTP. If users type HTTP first then you do a redirect, then use HSTS, or HSTS preload, or tell your users to always type https first

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan thanks ! I found [this](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-09/Marlinspike/BlackHat-DC-09-Marlinspike-Defeating-SSL.pdf) presentation which is about `sslstrip` , i will research about HSTS too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly. Cookie data if discovered by a third party may be replayed to replicate functionality. Note that you say someone 'sniffs' the cookie over HTTPS, which, if everything is working as it should, would not happen. If you are asking if the encrypted values of SSL/TLS can be replayed to the same effect, no that cannot happen. The plaintext value is needed for this to work.

Comment: according to [this](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-09/Marlinspike/BlackHat-DC-09-Marlinspike-Defeating-SSL.pdf)  someone can replicate ssl too. thanks a bunch

Comment: No, that presentation does not say that. It does however communicate methods for removing the encryption layer though.

Comment: yeah in that way cookies are not safe at all right?

Comment: True, but in that way also nothing a client does is safe, so focusing on cookies is moot.

Answer (score 3):

The encryption key used during a connection (such as HTTPS) will not be the same for a different connection.  The actual key used for the connection is generated randomly on the client and encrypted using the server's public key (found in the certificate).  There are multiple sites that describe this but [here's one I found that explains it really well](http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/).

Note that sniffing the connection would not allow a third party to distinguish which part starts where in the data flow unless it knows the common key.

It is not entirely impossible to hack, considering that the NSA does this all day long, but it requires huge processing power for quite limited results.

Comment: @lasan you can upvote & accept answers to your own question even with low reputation

Comment: @1615903 yeah but need 15 to publicly display the vote :)

Answer (score 3):

> What if someone sniffs that encrypted random number and send it to the server as it is?

It won't work. Modern TLS is designed to resist replay attacks at multiple levels:

- Each client uses an ephemeral key.
- The sequence number is used in the nonce for AEAD modes.